# QR scanner with ZXing and ZBar doesn't read low quality codes on cards

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, zbar

I have made applications using **ZXing** and **ZBar** both. Both are working fine and read **good quality QR codes** always.

But problem is when I scan the code on a **card** which is **not** that much nice in **quality** it never scans. I even tried with **5 MP** camera device but same results. I tried many apps from Google play store but neither of them worked. Card is not of that much bad quality. Can anyone tell me the solution or suggest any other API for that. I know its not the API its the Quality of QR code. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the card Image [image]

Comment: You really should post a picture of it as it is essential to understand your scenario.

Comment: @SeanOwen- see the image above

Comment: This image is a complete mess. I'm afraid you'll need to use different codes, get a phone with a better camera or use an external scanner (connected via bluetooth). Are you sure the card is in focus and that there's no motion blur involved?

Comment: see i can read the soft copy of this card but the problem is the card quality...I have also used device with 5MP camera but didn't worked. what i am saying is it can read good quality qr codes with large data but if we write that code on cards and after some time card can become rough or of low quality na??

Comment: I don't even think that's a QR code. I don't know what it is but looks mostly like a printing error.

Comment: as i said it is a qr code but with large data ....i have its soft copy and device took a little time but scans that

Comment: From what I can make out, the right side is chopped off. There is no top-right finder pattern. The other "finder patterns" are severely misprinted -- looks like the data is inside the bulls-eye! Here's what a QR code looks like with a lot of data: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Qr-code-ver-40.png

Comment: Thanks @SeanOwen :) i think it will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try these settings on the ImageScanner,

```
scanner = new ImageScanner();
//Slows the frame, but does the job
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 1);
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 1);
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.ENABLE, 0);
// Only enable the codes your app requires
scanner.setConfig(Symbol.QRCODE, Config.ENABLE, 1);
```

Made a huge difference in my app.